# Al grabar se borra todo el contenido del fichero txt

Tags: java

Tengo una interfaz gráfica, en la que tengo un botón para salir y guardar. El problema que tengo es que al salir me borra el contenido del fichero txt.

```
public class botonSalirActionListener implements ActionListener {

private Ventana ventana;

FileOutputStream fos = null;
ObjectOutputStream oos = null; 

public botonSalirActionListener(Ventana ventana) {
    this.ventana = ventana;
}
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    String listaEstudiantes;

    listaEstudiantes = "Antes de salir guardar los listEstudiantes creados";
    ventana.escribirDatosDeSalida(String.format(listaEstudiantes));

    if(grabarFichero()) {
        System.out.println("Ya se han guardado");
        listaEstudiantes = "Se ha guardado el fichero txt";
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("No se ha podido guardar el fichero");
        listaEstudiantes = "El fichero .txt no se pudo guardar";
    }

    ventana.escribirDatosDeSalida(String.format(listaEstudiantes));
    listaEstudiantes = "Cerrar";  
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(ventana,
            listaEstudiantes,
            "Cierre Udima-Home", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

    System.exit(0);
}
```

Este es el método utilizado, pero al revisar el txt fuera del IDE todo son caracteres ilegibles.

```
private boolean grabarFichero() {
    boolean correcto = false;                   
    try {
        fos = new FileOutputStream(ventana.getRutaFichero());  
        oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);

        oos.writeObject(ventana.listEstudiantes);

        oos.close();

        correcto = true;
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error: "+e);
    }

    return correcto;
}
```

}

Al volver a iniciar el programa y listar el contenido del txt, está vacio.

Comment: ¿El contenido lo ves borrado cuando vuelves a iniciar el programa?, ¿antes de iniciar el archivo tiene contenido?

Comment: Al iniciar el programa en la interfaz gratifica existe un botón para ver, lo pulso y está el contenido. Al crear y después salir se borra todo.

Comment: Para poder ver el contenido una vez sales y entras tienes que hacer un método que cargue el contenido del archivo. Si usas la clase `ObjectOutputStream` para guardar, para cargarlo puedes usar `ObjectInputStream`. Pero como te he comentado en la respuesta estas clases trabajan con datos binarios.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se guardan caracteres ilegibles porque estás guardando el objeto que te devuelve la llamada a `ventana.getRutaFichero()`, pero serializado, no la cadena de texto que ese objeto contiene.

En Java, un objeto cualquiera tiene además de la información que guardas en sus atributos, referencias a su tipo dinámico, identificador único de objeto, etc. Y estás escribiendo todo eso en formato binario en el fichero.

Te sugiero escribir con escritores.

```
Writer escritor = new FileWriter("rutaFichero");
escritor.append("info del estudiante");    // O estudiante.toString() si lo has implementado
escritor.append("\n");
```

Comment: Gracias he conseguido que muestre el mensaje para guardar en el txt. Pero quizás es el método utilizado para guardar el que no esté funcionando.

Comment: `private void guardarEnFichero() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        File fichero = new File(this.rutaFichero);
        FileOutputStream outFichero = new FileOutputStream(fichero);
        OutputStreamWriter escritor = new OutputStreamWriter(outFichero);
  for (Estudiante estudiante : listEstudiantes) {
            escritor.write(estudiante.lineaCsv() + "\n");
            System.out.println(listEstudiantes);
        }
        escritor.close();
    }`

Comment: El código actualizado sería mejor que lo añadieras en una edición de tu pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

Estas utilizando una clase para guardar en formato binario `ObjectOutputStream`. Si quieres guardar en formato texto puedes usar la clase `FileWriter` o  `BufferedWriter`. Para usar estas clases tienes que usar el método `write()` y poner como parámetro el `String` que quieras almacenar.
Te copio un método con el que puedes hacerlo.

```
 public static void escribirTXT() {
    File ficheroTXT = new File("archivoTexto.txt");
        try {
            //CON TRUE SOBREESCRIBIMOS EL FICHERO SIN BORRAR INFO
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(ficheroTXT, true));
            
            bw.write("Escribir String.");
            
            bw.close();
            
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Ha habido algún problema en la escritura del fichero.");
            //e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```